# how to loop through structs?

Tags: json, swift, struct

I'm fetching data from coinDesk API to get bitcoin rate related to other currencies, I've created 3 structs to save this data, but it's not possible to loop through the struct to know how many items I have there...

that's my structure:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var bpi: currencies
}

struct currencies: Codable {
    var USD: info
    var GBP: info
    var EUR: info
}

struct info: Codable {
    var code: String
    var symbol: String
    var description: String
    var rate_float: Float
}
```

To save the data from API I just use:

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
```

It saves the data with no error but, when I try to loop through this data to populate tableViewCells it doesn't work.

what I'm doing know is...

```
let euro = jsonData.bpi.EUR
let dollar = jsonData.bpi.USD
let gbp = jsonData.bpi.GBP

let infos = [euro,dollar,gbp]

completion(infos)
```

This is sending the data to my `UITableView` and populating, but what if I had 500 currencies? it would not be practical at all.. how could I do this in a more effective way?

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put keys instead

```
struct Response: Codable {
  let bpi: [String:Info]
}

struct Info: Codable {
  let code: String
  let symbol: String
  let description: String
  let rate_float: Float
}
```

Then

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
print(jsonData.bpi["USD"])
```

so for all keys

```
let keys = Array(jsonData.bpi.keys)
let values = Array(jsonData.bpi.values)
```